# Unhandled exception at (msvcr120d.dll)

Tags: c++

Have written some code for university coursework. 
This code compiles and runs well on the machines at university - but does not run on my personal laptop. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (same as at Uni), running windows 10 via bootcamp on a 2015 Macbook.

Code compiles fine - prints the first few lines in console - then crashes, with the following error.

"Unhandled exception at 0x56BEA9E8 (msvcr120d.dll) in ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCC0."

```
int main()
{
    string wheel1[3], wheel2[3], wheel3[3];

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++) { wheel1[counter] = getSuit(); }
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++) { wheel2[counter] = getSuit(); }
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++) { wheel3[counter] = getSuit(); }

    return 0;
}
```

Have tried searching for solutions - but these generally seem to point towards some bad coding.

Have looked through for anything similar to the other errors I found, but nothing's jumping out at me.

Also unsure as to why this code would work flawlessly on one machine, and not on another...

All help much appreciated..!

- @Ian, Seems to be  `_ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));`in dbgdel.cpp, as called by `for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++) { wheel1[counter] = getSuit(); }`

  - Edit: Have removed all code irrelevant to error.

Comment: You really should figure out exactly which line is causing the exception.

Comment: When in *your* code does the crash happen?

Comment: Edit at bottom for when the debug breaks.

Comment: This usually happens when you dereference an uninitialized or dangling pointer.

Comment: ^ I wish I could claim to know what this means... But I'm afraid I do not.

Comment: Check those loops again, how many elements is there in `wheel1`, `wheel2` and `wheel3`? How many elements do you iterate over?

Comment: Ding, ding, ding! Thanks Joachim. 
No thanks to my uni computers for handling this without error!

Comment: @Jack *No thanks to my uni computers for handling this without error!* --  It's not the uni computers that are at fault.  That's how C++ works if you go out-of-bounds of an array -- anything can happen.

Comment: `string wheel1[3], wheel2[3], wheel3[3];` - This line looks almost as if it was made to be hard to read and understand. Put every declaration on its own line, or better yet, make it a single variable: `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> wheels` or `std::array<std::array<std::string, 3>, 3> weels`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array wheel1,wheel2 and wheel3 allocates memory for 3 string objects while in the for loop you will try to access the 4th element for which space hasn't been allocated.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++) { wheel1[counter] = getSuit(); }
```

At some point counter will become 3 and then your code will try to access a memory block illegally. 
Either modify your loop so that counter goes till 3 or increase the size of the array by 1.

Comment: ... :') It had to be something ridiculous...!

Problem solved! - Now on to the part where I throw my university computers out of a window for not picking up on this! 

Many thanks.

Comment: @Jack It has nothing to do with the computers "not picking up on this".  When you access an array element that's out of bounds, the behavior of the program becomes undefined.  That means anything can happen, including "work", not work, work today but not tomorrow, work on a 1,000 computers and fail on computer 1,001., etc.